# Does the word "character" in "character development" refer to a fictional character or "character" as in the psychological qualities of someone?

Tags: expressions

Basically, does the term mean that the character is developing or that the "character of the character" is developing?

Comment: Could you be more realistic, please? From the title, I was about to say either or both, depending on the circumstances.

From your “explanation” less is clear. ‘does the term mean that the character is developing or that the "character of the character” is developing’ broadly disappears up its own definition, don’t you think?

Could you please demonstrate a use of “character” in “character development” where at least the context, if not the specific wording, made it wholly obvious whether you meant the development of a fictional character or of the psychological qualities of someone?

Answer (score -2):

It refers to the development of a fictional character.

In the latter sense, 'character building' would probably be used instead.

Comment: It seems to me it could be either.

Comment: I agree.  I meant that conventionally if I heard 'character development' I would think of the first meaning.  If I heard 'character building' I would think of the second.

Comment: So why don't you put that in the answer?